# VS Code to tracking changing to the wrong Repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have copy of VS Code that is tracking far too many changes than I have made. It also references a repo that I cloned a file from.

[image]

I need to fix this, as I am unable to commit anything via the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely one of two things has happened.

1. You opened a folder which is it not itself a git repository, but which contains numerous git repositories.
2. You opened a git repository which, for whatever reason, has other git repositories nested inside it.

In either case, VS Code will recursively find all of the inner repositories, and check for pending changes in all of them.

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue. Had multiple `.git` files in folders as far as my `usr`. Deleted them and problem solved